# List of WallpaperService onCommands?

Tags: android, wallpaper

What's the list of actions that the WallpaperService onCommand can receive? Couldn't find it in the docs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only standard ones are those defined by WallpaperManager:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html

(drop, tap, secondary tap).

Applications are free to define their own commands, so for anything else that an app may be reporting you will just need to talk with the app author or look at what they are generating.